# Apache  RewriteRule unexpected behaviour when two rules match URL at one moment (add path info postfix)

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I'm playing with apache rewrite_mod (Apache/2.2.17 Win32) and encounter very weird behave of rewriteRule.

My script primarily rewrite infinite filter parameters named `f1 .. f<infinity>` from nice url and in loop adding them as query variables, add path as query, and page number.

It works flawlessly, but if I add one another rule (last rule in script)

```
RewriteRule   ^(.+)\.html$                       /index.php?path=$1.html [QSA]
```

which is for another cases, it change execution of rewriterule at start of script.

Input URL:

```
http://testing.loc/some/thing/index0-f1-nice-cars-f2-planes-f3-karts-f4-bike.html
```

Expected result in PHP after all rewrites:

```php
$_SERVER[QUERY_STRING] => path=some/thing/&page=0&f1=nice-cars&f2=planes&f3=karts&f4=bike
$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
```

Script look like this (next part is flawlessly functional):

```
# from: some/thing/index0-f1-nice-cars-f2-planes-f3-karts-f4-bike.html
# to:   some/thing/index0.html?f=-f1-nice-cars-f2-planes-f3-karts-f4-bike

RewriteRule   ^(.*/?index[0-9]*)((?:-f[0-9]+-.+?)+)\.html$   /$1.html?f=$2 [QSA]

# from: some/thing/index0.html?f=-f1-nice-cars-f2-planes-f3-karts-f4-bike
# to    index.php?path=some/thing/&page=0&f=-f1-nice-cars-f2-planes-f3-karts-f4-bike

#              (   $1   )     (  $2  )
RewriteRule   ^(.+/{0,1})index([0-9]*)\.html$    /index.php?path=$1&page=$2 [QSA]

# while in f is something like "f1-nice-cars" (for example)
# remove "f1-nice-cars" from f and add as query "f1=nice-cars"

#                              (%1)    (   %2  ) ( %3)(       %4       )
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&f=-(f[0-9]+)-(.+?)((?:-f[0-9]+-.+)*)$ 
RewriteRule   ^index\.php$                       /index.php?%1&%2=%3&f=%4 [L]

# remove empty "f=" from query

RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&f=$ 
RewriteRule   ^index\.php$                       /index.php?%1
```

here, after rules is url in shape:

```
index.php?path=some/thing/&page=0&f1=nice-cars&f2=planes&f3=karts&f4=bike
```

**Without next rule in script is everything perfectly functional**. But if I add it, this rule itself do nothing, but rewrite_mod add something more to subtitution at start of script.

```
# rewrite rule for other paths without filters

RewriteRule   ^(.+)\.html$                       /index.php?path=$1.html [QSA]
```

Actually after run all script result is:

```
index.php?path=/some/thing/index0.html/some/thing/index0&f1=nice-cars&f2=planes&f3=karts&f4=bike
```

Comment: Have you proved/debugged this by removing all rules except this "problem" rule and giving it your "after rules" url?

Comment: I tested it, and that "problem" rule do nothing.

Comment: I don't understand your question then. `^(.+)\.html$` should do nothing: your url doesn't end with `html`. Why don't you rephrase your question to ask for the regex/rule that does what you want - provide sample input and output

Comment: Please before critism my question, read it all. I said, that should do nothing, but do something weird at normal run. I give all test outputs and write what happened at normal run and if it is splitted to non problem and problem part. I was searching more and found something interesting. It is called "add path info postfix" manipulation which rewrite mod using in some cases, and it is considered as bug. At this time, I don't know what is it exactly, but I will search more. This situation can happen when two of rules from one .htacces "fit" url, then rewrite_mod add something to subtitution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found resolution of this problem.
When 2 rules match URL at one pass of .htaccess, then apache rewrite_mod use method "add path info postfix" (its something like bug or feature), which ruin path of request. So when I added flag [L] to that 2 rules, result is OK.

I thinked that apache pass .htaccess sequentially and does not matter on next rules...